# memory full with views and crash

Tags: ipad, memory-management, view, memory-leaks, sdk

I have a problem with my application. I have 18 views but when you view every time step consumes more memory. After the application is crash.

```
while ([self.view.subviews count] > 0) { 
        [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview]; 
    }

    [self presentViewController:[[proj_lletrac_14_ontroller alloc] init] animated:NO completion:nil];
    [proj_lletrac_14_Controller release];
    [proj_lletrac_13_Controller release];
```

This code is a small example

My english is bad, I speak spanish :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your passing in an allocated object and not releasing it. You need to have it in a variable so you can release it:

```
proj_lletrac_14_ontroller *viewController = [[proj_lletract_14_ontroller alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
[viewController release];
```

So in steps your allocating an instance to a variable:

```
proj_lletrac_14_ontroller *viewController = [[proj_lletract_14_ontroller alloc] init];
```

Passing the instance to the presentViewController method:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Now you don't need to worry about the instance so you release your allocated object:

```
[viewController release];
```

Simple memory management.

Never allocate an object when passing in to functions unless you stick it in an autorelease pool:

```
[self presentViewController:[[[proj_lletrac_14_ontroller alloc] init] autorelease] animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But this is bad memory management practice. You should release everything you know that you don't need again.